# mkdocs: how to attach a downloadable file

Tags: python, markdown, mkdocs, mkdocs-material

I have a mkdocs project that resembles the following:

```
project
├─mkdocs.yml
├─docs
│ ├─home.md
│ ├─chapter1.md
│
├─static
  ├─file.ext
  ├─image.png
```

I am trying to find a way to "attach" `file1.ext` to the build, for instance as a link in `chapter1.md`.

Any suggestions how to achieve that? Detail: I want the file to be downloadable on click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `mkdocs`, to get the file to be downloadable on click using `markdown`, first you need to add this to your `mkdocs.yml` file :

```
markdown_extensions:
  - attr_list
```

and then in your `chapter1.md` you can add `download` attribute to your link  ... like so :

```
[file.ext](../static/file.ext){:download}
```

Heck you can even name the downloaded file:

```
[file.ext](../static/file.ext){:download="awesome-file"}
```

---

### **Explanation**

MkDocs converts Markdown to HTML using [Python-Markdown](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/) which offers a flexible extension mechanism, which makes it possible to change and/or extend the behavior of the parser without having to edit the actual source files.

The `markdown_extensions` in `mkdocs.yml` setting specifies the Python-Markdown extensions for MkDocs.
adding `attr_list` entry point enables the [Python-Markdown attribute lists](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/attr_list/) extension, which adds support for HTML-style attributes using curly brackets `{}` and a CSS-like syntax.

**example:**

let's say we want to open a link in new tab, we can achieve this like so :

```
[Google](https://www.google.com){:target="_blank"}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Check the answer by @WaLid LamRaoui

**Original:**
Fixed it with:

```markdown
// in chapter1.md
<a href="../static/file.ext" download>file.ext</a>
```

the mardownish like did not work:

```markdown
[file.ext](file::///../static/file.ext)
```

Comment: Hi .. i answered your question using the markdown way .. give it a try :)

Answer (score -1):

In your chapter1.md file you should link your file1.ext, this file should be located in the static folder.
You can link it like:
`[Link to file1](../static/file1.ext)`
After this you can build your project.

Comment: That works for figures, not for files.

Answer (score -2):

Place the file in the static directory:

1. Move or copy the file.ext to the static directory in your project structure.

```
Project
  ├─mkdocs.yml
  ├─docs
  | ├─home.md
  | ├─chapter1.md
  |
  ├─static
    ├─file.ext
    ├─image.png
```

2.Update your markdown file (chapter1.md) to include a link to the file:

```
In the chapter1.md file, you can add a Markdown link that points to the file you want to attach. For example:
[Download File](../static/file.ext)
```

3.Adjust the file path  ../static/file.ext  according to your project structure and the actual location of the file within the static directory